# Is there a way to know if a video file was downloaded from a torrent site?

Tags: video, bittorrent, metadata

If the user provides me with a video file, say, A.MP4, is it possible for me to extract certain information from the same file to know if it was downloaded from a torrent site or any other source likewise?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no information added to the file that would allow you to identify its source.  If this were not the case, a lot of people would not be using torrents for less than legal reasons.

Comment: How about embedding copyright information in the metadata of the video file? One can easily look for such information in order to point out piracy. [link](http://www.planetoftunes.com/projectmanagement/copyright/copyembed.html)

Comment: @GauravMishra Its true you can embed those metadata information, but that has to be done when creating the video file. Or somehow done by the torrent client. If you only have the video file, it will be whatever is there. And chances are it won't have the "downloaded from thisrandom.site.com" metadata. It may have data about the movie itself, if whoever encoding the movie bothered to put them in.